# Is there a registry key to tell windows to delete a file at next startup?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Is there a registry key to tell windows to delete a file at next startup?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the values are stored in the registry key

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

but you'd better use a tool for this, like [**MoveFile**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx), or [**MoveLatr**](http://www.bitsum.com/other.php#movelatr) from [BitSum](http://www.bitsum.com) ([C source code](http://www.bitsum.com/files/sources/movelater_cpp.html) provided for the latter), which do the registry editing for you.

Comment: That sounds like what I need.  I will look at it tomorrow and accept the answer if that's it.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i haven't gotten back to this yet, but don't worry I won't forget :)

Comment: I been on another project for the past two weeks, but I will get back to this eventually I promise lol.

Comment: Thanks Snark!  That was the correct registry key that I needed, and I was able to discover the ::MoveFileEx function by looking at that source code; It was exactly what I needed!! Thanks again!.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your registry and use the right click menu:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
@="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Currentversion\\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c DEL /F /Q \\\"%1\\\"\" /f\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
@="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Currentversion\\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c RD /S /Q \\\"%1\\\"\" /f\""
```

Comment: This puts the "Delete on Reboot" item in the right-click menu, but it doesn't seem to actually delete the chosen files on Windows 10.  Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like it schedules the file to be deleted during the next login, which isn't the same thing as deleting it during system startup. It may already be in use by then.